# How to integrate VS Code theme to WebStorm

Tags: visual-studio-code, themes, webstorm

I am using "Popping and Locking" color theme in VS Code and I want to use same theme in WebStorm also. But VS Code is using `.vsix` extention and WebStorm is using `.icls`

How can I convert `.vsix` to `.icls` or how can I use same theme in WebStorm. Am I have to do it manually?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Visual Studio Code themes can be implemented in two different ways, using a JSON file of properties, or using a tmTheme. If you look at the repository of your colour theme (https://github.com/hedinne/popping-and-locking-vscode for the theme you mentioned), you can see that it uses the JSON format.

tmThemes and JSON themes can be converted to a JetBrains theme with their official tool (https://github.com/JetBrains/colorSchemeTool).

---

I haven't used this tool or tested the functionality, so I don't know for sure that this will work. However, it looks to be quite straightforward. You can check the code of the colorSchemeTool yourself, but I believe you will need to do the following:

1. Download the colorSchemeTool code
2. Download the popping-and-locking JSON file (https://github.com/hedinne/popping-and-locking-vscode/blob/master/themes/popping-and-locking.json)
3. Move the JSON file to the vscThemes folder of the colorSchemeTool
4. Run the `convert.sh` script
5. The .icls file will now be placed under intellijThemes

---

Again, I haven't tested the functionality myself, but this seems to be the way to do it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. When I try to run convert.sh I recevie an error that says "stdout is not a tty".
Do you have any idea about this issue?

Comment: I also found same discussion but it didn't work for me unfortunately

Comment: I found the solution. I explained it here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45890339/stdout-is-not-a-tty-using-bash-for-node-tape-tap-spec

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can check https://github.com/mkubdev/material-vscode-jetbrains to get the color scheme of the dark+ theme from Visual Code for Webstorm. And the .xml to add to the plugin Material UI.

1. Download both files
2. Download Material UI Plugin
3. Add .xml file to Custom Material Theme to get the UI
4. Add .icls to replace the colorScheme

Voila!