# How do I profile a node.js program from start to end?

Tags: node.js, profiling, profiler

Suppose I have a node.js cli program that can be run as `node some-program.js` and it exits in 10 seconds. How do I profile it? I want to get flame graphs and time spent in each functions.

Answer (score 1):

`node --prof some-program.js` will produce an `isolate-*` for each worker thread.

`node --prof-process isolate...` will produce a user-friendly output.

You need some experience to be able to read it - but basically your program spends time in three ways: executing JS code, compiling JS code and running system libraries.

Comment: Note that if you run into a `stdout is not a tty` error after running `node --prof-process ...`, you'll need to run `node.exe ...` instead of `node ...` as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/62532536/7808223