# In Git Bash, how do I fix a "stdin is not a tty" error?

Tags: windows-10, stdin, psql, git-bash, tty

I'm using Git Bash on Windows 10.  I would like to import a SQL file to be run in my PostGres 12 local database.  I tried the below

```
$ PGPASSWORD=$DB_PASSWORD psql -U${DB_USER} $DB_NAME < scripts/my-script.sql
stdin is not a tty
```

When I look in my database, the script hasn't been run, which leads me to believe the error message is telling me why, except I'm not sure what it means or how to fix it.

Comment: Did you try `winpty`? Did you search other related answers before you posted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use redirection on Windows (in general, not just in "git-bash").

Pass the script file using the `-f` parameter:

```
PGPASSWORD=$DB_PASSWORD psql -U${DB_USER} -f scripts/my-script.sql $DB_NAME
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? While in general "Don't use ... Windows" suits my taste, I can and do use redirections in Git Bash quite often. Is there a particular problem with `psql`? Or some other pitfall that I need to be watching for? I agree with your answer though -- simple and direct is almost always best.

Comment: This command isn't working for me on Git Bash.  I get a 'psql: warning: extra command-line argument "-f" ignored' warning and I'm then logged in to a normal psql session.

Comment: @Dave: sorry, `$DB_NAME` must be the last parameter

Answer (score 0):

Replace `psql` with `psql.exe`

It has to do with the aliases that git-bash ships - psql is one of the handful of programs which has an alias. When I run `cat  /etc/profile.d/aliases.sh` I see this line:

`for name in node ipython php php5 psql python2.7 winget`

For more information, check out these links:

- https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/2651#issuecomment-693569276
- https://github.com/pinojs/pino-pretty/issues/305#issuecomment-1114950822
- [stdout is not a tty. Using bash for node + tape + tap-spec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45890339/stdout-is-not-a-tty-using-bash-for-node-tape-tap-spec)